# vba code to insert new row based on two columns condition

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to insert a row when there is a value change in two-column cells in an excel
For example, columns F and G where F has a string value of "Buy" and "Sell" and column G has string "D" and "S".

My code creates a blank row only on one column condition, which is when the value changes a blank row is added.

```
Sub InsertRowsAtValueChange()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    If WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
        WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But the code should add a row when the column is sorted and when the last value is
"Buy" - "D"
"Buy" - "S"
"Sell" - "D"
"Sell" - "S"

The image shows what I am trying to achieve.[Code should work to create the bottom requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g78P1.png)

Comment: Seems like you want to use a different column number than `1` in `Cells(i, 1)` and `Cells(i - 1, 1)`. Based on your screenshot, it seems like the row is inserted only when column G changes, but you could add a condition to check if column F changes as well (using `Or`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty straight forward, you just need to add an OR clause to your if condition:

```
Sub InsertRowsAtValueChange()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    If WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value _
    Or WorkRng.Cells(i, 2).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
       
        WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

(I added the "_" just to wrap it onto the next line for readability)